# Numbering the pages in LyX

Tags: lyx, page-numbering

Can someone help me understand how to make the pages in LyX numbered in Roman numerals? also how can i set a page number according to me like if i want vii instead of i at first page ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `Document | Settings | Latex Preamble` and insert

```
\pagenumbering{Roman}
```

and you should be done.

If you want lower case roman numberals, use `\pagenumbering{roman}`

Answer (score 3):

In the [wiki page of LyX](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Numbering#frontmatter) you can see:

> #### How can I have roman pagination (i, ii, iii...) for the first part of my document?
>
> If you use a book class, simply insert
>
> ```
> \frontmatter
> ```
>
> at the beginning of the document. This will switch page numbering to
>   roman (i, ii, iii...)
>
> ```
> \mainmatter
> ```
>
> will switch back to arabic (1, 2, ...) and start from "1".
>
> With report or article classes, insert at the beginning (in the LaTeX
>   preamble):
>
> ```
> \pagenumbering{roman}
> ```
>
> and then, where you want to switch back (somewhere on the page in the
>   normal text), in ERT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>):
>
> ```
> \pagenumbering{arabic}
> \setcounter{page}{1}
> ```